# Why is it doing this? Default padding or margin property?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a [site](http://store.viddir.com/storefront.html). In bottom left container is my genre nav. I had to apply a negative margin property to get my `li`'s in the right place. It seems that there is a top padding property of approximately 15px. Why is it doing this? I don't see anything in the code that code be causing this. It should be flush top and left right?

Comment: You should include the relevant code in your question, or in a jsfiddle. Just referring to a live page makes the question rather meaningless as soon as the page has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the default margin of `ul` tag.

You can just reset it by providing this:

```
ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

You can probably conside using some css [reset rules](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) for your website.

Comment: Oh cool, thank you. I'm learning something new all the time.